# What can I do with a crossover ethernet cable?

Tags: ethernet, lan, layer1, cable

Is the file sharing of two PCs, connected with a crossover cable, both directions or only one?

Would I be able to connect to a PC and play LAN games over this mini-network?

Would this be extremely fast?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the modern NICs (network interface cards) do not require a crossover Ethernet cable. You can connect them with a straight-through cable and the NIC will flip one of the ends into crossover (the technology is called Auto-MDIX).

Back in the early days this was a requirement when you wanted to connect two computers to use a crossover cable but since NICs evolved with this technology, it is no longer a requirement.

And yes, you will be able to play LAN or exchange files between these two computers.

It will be fast enough to play - 100Mbps or 1Gbps (depends on your NIC).

I hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Does this apply to PCIe network cards or also motherboard ethernet ports. And can you maybe tell me or make a approximation of which year the ports are from and would have these features.

Comment: @Jeroentetje3 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=MDI-X&year_start=1990&year_end=2018 gives you a good idea of when it arrived as a technology

Answer (score 1):

Both directions, yes, and yes.

If it's gigabit capable then it will auto mdx (no crossover cable necessary) if it's only 100 mb then you're better off using a crossover cable, but you can check for auto mdx somewhere in the settings for you network adapter, Linux it's just ethtool I think.

Seen people get a 40 gbit point to point connecting going, it's beautiful.

Comment: Does only one of the 2 connected pc's need an auto-MDX?

Comment: Yes, the Auto-MDX feature works if it is available on one or on two neighbouring interfaces.